# .svg georeference?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, georeferencing, illustrator, inkscape

How would I go about taking a layer from AI or Inkscape and importing it into Arc?

I've got a vector drawing I want to use and I know I need to georeference it but I'm lost as to how. I also can't seem to import it as a shapefile.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  You mention `.svg` in your title but not in your Question body (the contents of which it should be summarizing).  Would you be able to use the edit button beneath your Question to explain the SVG connection, please?  Also, I am assuming that AI is Adobe Illustrator but that is an abbreviation that I think should be spelled out the first time it is used in a Question.

Comment: in Adobe Illustrator you can export to dxf - this will be non georeferenced but view-able in ArcGIS desktop. then use the georefencing tools for CAD http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001000000010000000 convert to shape gdb after.

Comment: @Mapperz I think you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Mapperz:

> in Adobe Illustrator you can export to dxf - this will be non
>   georeferenced but view-able in ArcGIS desktop. then use the
>   georefencing tools for CAD
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001000000010000000
>   convert to shape gdb after.