# Converting GeoPDF to ArcGIS with annotations (arcmap original labels)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, convert, annotation, geopdf

I've got a GeoPDF file that contains vector and annotation data (arcmap labels). I need to convert it into a feature class.

I've tried to follow the former questions that been asked here:

- [Adding PDF (especially GeoPDF) to ArcMap as data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53023/adding-pdf-especially-geopdf-to-arcmap-as-data)
- [Converting GeoPDF to vector format like CAD or shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/convert-geopdf-to-a-vector-format)

I've succeeded to convert the file into .dwg/.dxf files by using the "[Any PDF to DWG](http://any-pdf-to-dwg-converter.en.softonic.com/)" software. The output was an ungeoreferenced and annotations-less .dwg.

1. How to convert the GeoPDF file to .dwg/.dxf without loosing the annotations layer?
2. How to keep GeoPDF's source georeferencing?

Comment: These ones are also promising, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72674/georeference-vector-linework and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84231/svg-georeference. I used Inkscape and Linear Referencing tools once to do the same procedure and remember that georeferencing vector data can be a real trouble. I was able to extract polygons but did not try annotations but it should be fine as long as you filter right elements in Inkscape to export into DXF.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.